# python: If loop returns wrong result

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

I wrote the following script trying to calculate portions in array a and stack the result to the original array:

```
import numpy


a = numpy.array([[1, 4, 4.555],
                 [2, 3, 9.112],
                 [3, 1, 7.322],
                 [1, 5, 3.911]])

i = 0
b = numpy.ones((4,1))
if i <= 2:
    b[i][0] = float(a[i][2])/(a[i][2]+a[i+1][2])
    b[i+1][0] = float(a[i+1][2])/(a[i][2]+a[i+1][2])
    i = i+2
print b
c = numpy.hstack((a,b))
print c
```

But the result were strange:

```
array b:
[[ 0.33328455]
 [ 0.66671545]
 [ 1.        ]
 [ 1.        ]]
array c:
[[ 1.          4.          4.555       0.33328455]
 [ 2.          3.          9.112       0.66671545]
 [ 3.          1.          7.322       1.        ]
 [ 1.          5.          3.911       1.        ]]
```

The first and second rows of array c was what I want, but the rest rows were strange. The result array I expected is:

```
[[ 1.          4.          4.555       0.33328455]
 [ 2.          3.          9.112       0.66671545]
 [ 3.          1.          7.322       0.65182943]
 [ 1.          5.          3.911       0.34817057]]
```

How to fix this? And is there more efficient coding to do this task?

Comment: So what is your *expected* output? Note that you *do not have a loop*. You only have an `if` statement. The code won't repeat there. Did you mean to use a `while i <=2:` loop perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an *if loop*. An `if` statement will execute a block if the test matches, but will only execute it *once*. Your `i = i+2` statement at the end of the block won't cause the code to be repeated.

You probably wanted a `while` loop there:

```
while i <= 2:
    b[i][0] = float(a[i][2]) / (a[i][2] + a[i+1][2])
    b[i+1][0] = float(a[i+1][2]) / (a[i][2] + a[i+1][2])
    i += 2
```

`while` repeatedly executes the block as long as the test is true.

You could use a `for` loop too, with an `xrange()` object that increments in steps of 2:

```
for i in xrange(0, len(b), 2):
    b[i][0] = float(a[i][2]) / (a[i][2] + a[i+1][2])
    b[i+1][0] = float(a[i+1][2]) / (a[i][2] + a[i+1][2])
```

Either way, by looping the expected output is produced:

```
[[ 1.          4.          4.555       0.33328455]
 [ 2.          3.          9.112       0.66671545]
 [ 3.          1.          7.322       0.65182943]
 [ 1.          5.          3.911       0.34817057]]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my noob question. Is there other way to create array b to put portions in, instead making it numpy ones in the very beginning?

Comment: I don't know enough about numpy or even your problem to answer that, sorry.